# document and edges in orientdb

Tags: database-design, graph, document-oriented

I was playing around with OrientDB lately and was create some classes and edges. I was able to create edges between documents, is this something that is expected from OrientDB when edges are relationship between vertices?

Besides that, how do I manage data integrity when I delete a document from the DB, apparently the edges are still pointing to an unknown record id that is already deleted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How you did delete the edges? Please use `DELETE VERTEX`, not plain SQL `DELETE` to preserve edges. Starting from 2.0.x, OrientDB provided a warning to avoid deletion of verices/edges by using SQL DELETE.

Comment: I'm using OrientDB 2.0 and `DELETE VERTEX` doesn't work on document that have edges, it will throw an error. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The document received is not a Vertex. Found class 'User'`. Am I in the wrong direction? Thanks

Comment: If you work with documents, you can't have edges. I think you mixed both model in wrong way. How did you create an edge on a document that is not a vertex?

Comment: `create class User`, `create class Social`, `create class Owns extends E`, `Create edge Owns from {user.rid} to {social.rid}`. These are the commands that I have executed. Please advice